# Using phpcrawl with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpcrawl

I am trying to use cuab's PHPCrawl within Laravel 5.4 and have included it through composer using this package:
https://packagist.org/packages/mmerian/phpcrawl

I have tried running this sample code:

```
class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler  
{ 
  function handleDocumentInfo($DocInfo)  
  { 
    if (PHP_SAPI == "cli"){
      $lb = "\n"; 
    } else {
      $lb = "<br />"; 
    }
    echo "Page requested: ".$DocInfo->url." (".$DocInfo->http_status_code.")".$lb; 
    echo "Referer-page: ".$DocInfo->referer_url.$lb; 

    if ($DocInfo->received == true) {
      echo "Content received: ".$DocInfo->bytes_received." bytes".$lb; 
    }
    else {
      echo "Content not received".$lb;  
    }

    echo $lb; 
    flush(); 
  }  
} 

$crawler = new MyCrawler(); 
$crawler->setURL("www.php.net"); 
$crawler->addContentTypeReceiveRule("#text/html#"); 
$crawler->addURLFilterRule("#\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$# i"); 
$crawler->enableCookieHandling(true);  
$crawler->setTrafficLimit(1000 * 1024); 
$crawler->go(); 
$report = $crawler->getProcessReport(); 

if (PHP_SAPI == "cli") {
  $lb = "\n"; 
} else {
  $lb = "<br />"; 
}

echo "Summary:".$lb; 
echo "Links followed: ".$report->links_followed.$lb; 
echo "Documents received: ".$report->files_received.$lb; 
echo "Bytes received: ".$report->bytes_received." bytes".$lb; 
echo "Process runtime: ".$report->process_runtime." sec".$lb;
```

But it throws multiple errors like this:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPCrawler' not found

How would you reference the correct namespace so that I can use the script within Laravel?

Comment: You can either include the file manually or add a [class map](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) to your composer.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the files via a class map in your composer.json file. You can see an example of what the class map looks like on their [github page](https://github.com/mmerian/phpcrawl/blob/master/composer.json), which at the time of writing looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "libs/Utils/PHPCrawlerUtils.class.php",
        "libs"
    ]
}
```

You'll have to prefix the files with `vendor/mmerian/phpcrawl` or whatever the path is to the libs folder.